# Consumer Client Spring Rest Post Service Throwing: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request

Tags: spring, rest, service

**Service Details:**

```
End point Url: Some url
Request Body: {"userIds":["someID123456789"]}
Header: application/json
```

**SpringConfig.xml**

```
<bean id="rumbaDeleteUserClient"  class="com.app.services.UserServiceImpl">       
        <property name="deleteUserTemplate" ref="deleteUserTemplate"/>
     </bean>

     <bean id="deleteUserTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonConverter"/>
                <ref bean="stringConverter"/>
                <ref bean="encodedType"/>
                <ref bean="marshallingConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="requestFactory" ref="deleteUserRequestFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="deleteUserRequestFactory" class= "org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
        <property name="readTimeout" value="${connection.read.timeout}" />
        <property name="connectTimeout" value="${connection.timeout}" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="jsonConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="stringConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="*"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="marshallingConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
        <constructor-arg ref="ulcServiceMarshaller"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="olcServiceMarshaller"/>
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="encodedType"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="*"/>
    </bean>
<bean id="ulcServiceMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
      <property name="contextPath" value="com.pearson.psn.rumba.model" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="olcServiceMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
      <property name="contextPath" value="com.pearson.psn.rumba.org.model" />
    </bean>
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
    private RestTemplate deleteUserTemplate;
    public void setDeleteUserTemplate(RestTemplate deleteUserTemplate) {
            this.deleteUserTemplate = deleteUserTemplate;
        }

    public void method1() {
    String uri = "some end point url";
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factroy = (HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) deleteUserTemplate
                        .getRequestFactory();
                deleteUserTemplate.setRequestFactory(factroy);

    String[] userArray = new String[1];
                userArray[0] = "someID123456789";
    // create request body
                JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
                request.put("userIds", userArray);

    // body
                HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(request.toString());

    ResponseEntity<String> response = deleteUserTemplate.postForEntity(uri,
                        requestEntity, String.class);

}
```

As its a POST type service, I tried with postForObject and exchange method also, its not working. I guess the way which i am passing request body is wrong. So how to pass the request body when it is like {"userIds":["someID123456789"]}

Can any one give your thoughts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: when using external tool like postman or such are you able to get 200 ok?

Comment: Ya, its working on Rest Client when i do from Browser. I am able to get 200 Ok. It's not working when i am calling from Java. i.e. The consumer client which i have written is not working.